# What does this one byte mean in NALu

Tags: networking, mpeg2-ts

For NALu (Network abstraction Layer Units) I can interpret below

000000 0109f000 00000167....

00000001 -> Start code prefix

09 -> NALu type.

**f0 -> ??**

00000001 -> Start code prefix

67 -> SPS

So what is the meaning of **f0**?

**UPDATED**

As answered in comments, F0 means that any slice type will be present in this NAL.

FYI

```
(primary_pic_type = 0xe) + rbsp stop one bit = 0xf0
```

Comment: its a mask. 0xF0 means the AU may contain any nalu type.

Comment: @szatmary May I ask you mask bits for what? How we assume this AU contains any nalu type?

Comment: It's not an assumption. It's a fact. These fields are well documented in the AVC specification.

Comment: @szatmary I don't doubt. Could you explain the name of this mask? I'm looking AVC specification.